# get the top 30 gainer stocks from YQL

Tags: c#, yahoo, yql, stocks

I am stuck with figuring out how to get the top 30 stock gainers using YQL with yahoo. I understand how YQL works, but is there a LIMIT clause or SELECT TOP 30 feature in YQL? I know if there is a way to do that it would solve the issue, but ultimately what is a way to get the top 30 gainers? I am working with a C# application that processes info about the stocks and use the YQL to gather the info. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting top 30 is done like this:

`select * from geo.countries(30)`